# Reference connection strings in config from a separate project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-config, connection-string, config

I have a parent application which has a config file that contains connection strings.

I would like all child applications I develop to be able to reference this config file so I only have to update connection strings in one place.

**Parent Application web.config**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

**Parent Application ConnectionStrings.Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings>

    <add name="MyConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=***;Initial Catalog=***;Integrated Security=False; Password=***;User ID=***" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

</connectionStrings>
```

This works fine for bringing in data in the parent application.

I've added the ConnectionStrings.config file to my child application as a linked file and then reference it in the web.config as follows:

**Child Application web.config**

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

But when I run the child application I get the following error:

> Unable to open configSource file 'ConnectionStrings.config'.
>   (C:\Child Application\web.config line 8)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the build type to `content` and `copy to output directory` on the parent project's config file, and then referenced the file as `bin/ConnectionStrings.config`?

Answer (score 0):

Under the child project, open the file properties of the linked ConnectionStrings.config file and set `Copy To Output Directory` to `Copy always`. You have to do this in order for this file to be copied to the child project bin directory regardless of the setting for the parent project ConnectionString.config file.

Comment: The file isn't showing up in the bin/{BuildName} folder?

Comment: I did what you suggested and then ran in debug mode, but receive same error.

Comment: When you build, is the config file showing up in the build folder for the mode you're building?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use project post build steps and copy configuration file into output directory.